# Remote Debugging via Dbeaver Client

Tags: debugging, dbeaver

I have a jdbc driver and using Dbeaver as client application.
How should i debug the jar.
I am using Intellij IDEA and there is option for remote debugging, 
this is option available in intellij but i am not sure how to use it in Dbeaver.
`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777`

Answer (score 0):

add it to dbeaver.ini file that located in dbeaver installation directory